# How to loop through a folder?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to loop through a folder and import all the files into Access.

This is my code:

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8
Dim fso, MyFile, FileName, TextLine
Dim TextArray()
Dim x As Double
Dim SQLString

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FileName = "C:\Users\ava\Desktop\TEST_IMPORT\1.txt"

Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
    ReDim Preserve TextArray(x)
    TextLine = MyFile.ReadLine
    TextArray(x) = TextLine
    x = x + 1
Loop

MyFile.Close

SQLString = "INSERT INTO TEST_TAB (Layout, Anzahl_Etiketten, Anzahl_Verpackungseinheiten, Bezeichnung1, Selektionsnummer, Bezeichnung2, Barcode, LA_Nummer, RM_Nummer, Bezeichnung3, Teilenummer) VALUES ('" & TextArray(0) & "','" & TextArray(1) & "','" & TextArray(4) & "','" & TextArray(5) & "','" & TextArray(6) & "','" & TextArray(7) & "','" & TextArray(9) & "','" & TextArray(10) & "','" & TextArray(13) & "','" & TextArray(15) & "','" & TextArray(19) & "');"

DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)

DoCmd.RunSQL SQLString

DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOn)

End Sub
```

The code imports a text file from my desktop (1.txt) then imports the data into my Access DB.

This works for my one File. (1.txt)

I found [this link](http://codevba.com/office/loop_files_in_folder.htm#.Wa65LtAcyUk) how to loop through a folder.

How do I implement that into my code?

Comment: It might be actually helpful to explain what the code is doing, through which folder you want to loop, which type of file you want to select and such

Comment: i'll ad that in to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im assuming you are reading every file with extension `.txt` in the folder `C:\Users\ava\Desktop`.

Try this...

```
Dim TextArray()
Dim x As Double
Dim SQLString

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

strFolder= "C:\Users\ava\Desktop" 'sets folder
strFileName = Dir(strFolder & "\*.txt") 'grabs first txt file

Do While strFileName <> 0 'starts loop
    FileName = strFileName 'set filename

    Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

    '' Read from the file
    Do While MyFile.AtEndOfStream <> True
            ReDim Preserve TextArray(x)
            TextLine = MyFile.ReadLine
            TextArray(x) = TextLine
            x = x + 1   
    Loop

    MyFile.Close

    SQLString = "INSERT INTO TEST_TAB (Layout, Anzahl_Etiketten, Anzahl_Verpackungseinheiten, Bezeichnung1, Selektionsnummer, Bezeichnung2, Barcode, LA_Nummer, RM_Nummer, Bezeichnung3, Teilenummer) VALUES ('" & TextArray(0) & "','" & TextArray(1) & "','" & TextArray(4) & "','" & TextArray(5) & "','" & TextArray(6) & "','" & TextArray(7) & "','" & TextArray(9) & "','" & TextArray(10) & "','" & TextArray(13) & "','" & TextArray(15) & "','" & TextArray(19) & "');"

    DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOff)

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQLString

    DoCmd.SetWarnings (WarningsOn)

    strFileName = Dir 'Grabs next txt file
Loop
```

Comment: That gives me an Error....                                                                                                  BTW That is exactly what i try to do

Comment: runtime error 5 invalid procedure or invalid argument

Comment: Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

Comment: what is `FileName` showing up as on that line? do a `debug.print` to see what's being called.

Comment: outside the context

Comment: i'll be back tommorrow at 8:00 utc+1 ^^sry                                                                thanks for all the help

Comment: Make sure that the files are in the same directory as the desktop folder and not inside folders.That could be why you are getting the error

Comment: I'll check on that now

Comment: I changed it to a easyer path (C:\Users\ava\Desktop\TEST_IMPORT\1.txt) to enshure that is not the cause (it isen't)

Comment: i get an error with this line:  Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading) the eror ise the same...(runtime error)

Comment: im not sure why `FileName = strFileName` is not being set. it works fine on my end. The only thing I can think of is that there are no files in the location... when you tested above did you set `strFolder= "C:\Users\ava\Desktop\TEST_IMPORT"` ????

Comment: first i didn^t ^^ but i did after i saw that in my code and that gave me this error: Data Not Found ... but there are 3 .txt files in that folder...

Comment: does `strFileName= Dir(strFolder & "\*.txt")` give you anything?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are using TextArray over and over and over, but consider doing it like this.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()


        Dim strPathFile As String, strFile As String, strPath As String
        Dim strTable As String
        Dim blnHasFieldNames As Boolean

        ' Change this next line to True if the first row in EXCEL worksheet
        ' has field names
        blnHasFieldNames = True

        ' Replace C:\Documents\ with the real path to the folder that
        ' contains the EXCEL files
        strPath = "C:\Users\rschuell\Desktop\test\"

        ' Replace tablename with the real name of the table into which
        ' the data are to be imported
        strTable = "tablename"

        strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.txt")
        Do While Len(strFile) > 0
              strPathFile = strPath & strFile

              DoCmd.TransferText _
                TransferType:=acImportDelim, _
                TableName:=strTable, _
                FileName:=strPathFile, _
                HasFieldNames:=blnHasFieldNames


        ' Uncomment out the next code step if you want to delete the
        ' EXCEL file after it's been imported
        '       Kill strPathFile

              strFile = Dir()
        Loop



End Sub
```